# Is there such a thing as a muggle werewolf?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, muggles, werewolf

I was reading Fantastic Beasts and Where to find them, and I found this quote:

> “Werewolves spend most of their time as humans (**whether wizard or
> Muggle**).”

(Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them)

Does this mean, if a muggle is bitten by a werewolf, and somehow survives (rescued by wizards, then had their memory modified), that they will become a werewolf?

I may make a second question on this topic regarding how the wizarding world would remain hidden to this muggle, if they do indeed become a werewolf.

I am looking for canon answers based on JKR interviews, the books, or simply your own canon-based speculation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Muggles can become werewolves, if they survive the bite.

From J.K. Rowling on [Pottermore](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves):

> the great English authority on werewolves, Professor Marlowe Forfang,
> undertook the first comprehensive study of their habits. He found that
> nearly all those he managed to study and question had been wizards
> before being bitten. He also learned from the werewolves that Muggles
> ‘taste’ different to wizards and that they are much more likely to die
> of their wounds, whereas witches and wizards survive to become
> werewolves.